# In the series Counterpart, how do Baldwin and her Other share history?

Tags: counterpart-series

In the Starz series [Counterpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpart_(TV_series)), a parallel earth (Earth Prime) was created in 1987 in East Germany. The main character of the story, Howard Silk, has shared memories and experiences with his Other from Earth Prime because he was born before 1987, so they were one person until then.

Baldwin, an assassin from Earth Prime, has the shared memory of her father's death with her Other, but she appears to be in her 20s. In a flashback, she appears to be around ten years old at the time her father died, which would make her around 20 in 1997, 30 in 2007 and 40 when the series was released in 2017.

Is this a continuity error or is there another explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its is explained indirectly in the show.

Both sides didn't instantly diverge when the two earths split. Instead small changes started creeping in slowly on each side, leading to increasing differences.

It is not until:

> [1996 when the virus is released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpart_(TV_series)#Premise) that the two sides diverge dramatically

Based on this, she could be around 30 in the show's present, and still shared pretty much the same childhood up to around 10

Comment: Okay, I had wondered if lives began diverging as a result of the change introduced by Yanik or whether they ran in parallel for a while. How does Baldwin know when her life diverged from her Other?

Comment: @cr0m depends what information she was provided about her other before crossing, or what she was able to find out afterwards. She obviously remembers what events lead her down her own path, and can guess what might have happened otherwise. As for divergence, In the second season it shows that Emily & Howard follow a very similar path on both sides to begin with (i.e. both Howards worked in interface with Emily blocking promotions) until later on. Not entirely sure where the divergence there fits with the virus though.

Comment: Howard diverged much earlier than the flu, since Howard Prime and Emily Prime never married. That's why I wondered whether everyone's lives diverged shortly after the experiment that Yanik conducted with his Other.